# Fabric: Run command as root automatically

Tags: python, freebsd, fabric

I have some freebsd servers and don't have sudo. But I want to run some command automatically with root just like the following command:

```
def autodeploy(url):
    with cd('/tmp'):
        if not exists('releasetar.sh'):
            put('/tmp/releasetar.sh', 'releasetar.sh', mode=0644)
        run("wget '{}'".format(url))
        run('su - -m -c "cd /tmp && bash /tmp/releasetar.sh"')
```

the `su` with `-c` option worked to linux but didn't worked on freebsd. How can I solved this problem ? I'm wish your solution can both worked on linux and freebsd. Thank you for your answer~~

Answer (score 2):

If you're using fabric you can just provide the -u argument from the command line to specify which user you want to run the task as

`fab -u root <task name>`

For more options from the command line check out http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/usage/fab.html#command-line-options

You can also set your username programmatically

```
from fabric.api import run, settings

with settings(user="root"):
    run("some-command")
```

Comment: sorry,i find this did not work when i was a normal user on freebsd.It will not change to root automatically or ask me input the root password.

Comment: sorry, I don't have a freebsd machine so I cannot verify. Maybe look at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/faq.html it mentions some caveats for freebsd

Answer (score 0):

Install `sudo` from ports (`/usr/ports/security/sudo`).